# Can we add Condition in formula field, so that system can check the first condition and if false it will go the next condition?

Tags: formula, automation

I need to create a custom formula field in Salesforce that performs the following calculation for project duration:

1. If the project's end date (a custom date field) is after December 31, 2028, the formula should return 18 months.
2. If the end date is on or before December 31, 2028, the formula should calculate the difference between the project's end date and the expected launch date (another custom date field) and then divide that difference by 30 to return the value in months.
3. However, if the expected launch date is blank, the formula should calculate the difference between the project's end date and the close date, and then divide that difference by 30 to return the value in months.

Comment: Yes it is. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Please [edit] your question to show us the attempt you've made. If you're new to Salesforce (or a part/feature thereof) then https://trailhead.salesforce.com is going to be a better resource to help get you started.

Answer (score -2):

I managed to solve this problem with the following formula:

```
IF( 
    NOT(ISBLANK( Expected_Launch__c )),
    IF(
        Project_End_Date__c > DATE(2028,12,31), 
        18,
        (Project_End_Date__c - Expected_Launch__c) / 30
    ),
    IF(
        Project_End_Date__c > DATE(2028,12,31), 
        18,
        (Project_End_Date__c - CloseDate ) / 30
    )
)
```

Comment: Is this actually an answer to your question, or did you mean to add it to your question via an edit?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).